# Redux can't read function of state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I met really weird issue, which is related with redux-I think so. Below you can see `function getCurrentContent`, but if I tried to use it, It says there is no function like that

[image]

[image]

If I change like this,

[image]

It shows error.
[image]

Comment: are you using Immutable.js ?

Comment: Please copy+paste code into the question, rather than using screenshots of it

Comment: Its `EditorState` and in your mapStateToProps try to check the state argument what it contains. It maybe a spelling issue of your editorState

Comment: I'm using Draft.js and it use Immutable.js, I think so. And I'm saying sorry for that I Couldn't upload code, that's because of my dev env.

Comment: Is there maybe one `.editorState` too many in your `mapStateToProps`?